# HTML/CSS as a GUI for a python script?

Tags: python, html, css, dictionary

I have a python script that reads in a CSV file that represents teacher evaluations, I read in this script and feed the values into a 2D dictionary.

The dictionary goes like this: Teacher Names (key) > List of Questions for that teacher(key) > List of answers for each question.(value)

I want this in a more presentable way, so I'm thinking of creating a website for it.

You upload the CSV file to the website, the script makes the 2D dict, and then creates drop down menus from the elements of the dict.

So a drop down menu that shows all the teacher names, once you choose one you choose the question from another drop down menu with the list of questions, and then the answers are displayed.

How feasible is this? Or should I look for another method of doing this?

I'm proficient in python and a beginner in HTML/CSS (couple of sites).

Comment: Well it can certainly be done. 'Feasible' is a great way to phrase the question. If you're not familiar with python web applications, frameworks, CGI, file I/O on a server.... I hope you have some time :'D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sound like you basically want to write a web app in Python. That is, you want to write, essentially, a custom server that handles data received from clients and then sends HTML back to them.

This is very possible. To do it in a "modern" way, you'll want to use a [web framework](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WebFrameworks). Another (more oldschool and slow, but probably simpler) option would be to use a regular web server like Apache or NGINX which forwards data to/from clients and your Python program as a [CGI application](https://wiki.python.org/moin/CgiScripts).

Regardless of the method chosen, you'll want your Python script to:

- Serve an [HTML upload form](https://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/file.html) for the CSV data
- Receive the CSV data that the HTML form POSTs upon submission and interpret it
- Send back an HTML page containing the parsed CSV data

Comment: Thanks, you've given me enough keywords to start researching on. A sub-question if you don't mind: Since I'm going to have to learn whatever method I'm going have to use to present this python script, do you think I should stick with doing it via a web framework, or should I look into other methods of creating a "GUI" for my script?

Comment: @Kxa I would do it via a web framework. From what I understand about your goal, you don't need a local head to your Python program...you want remote users to be able to interact with it via a website. So, in a non-traditional sense, the website that your Python program "serves" via the web framework you choose will function as it's GUI. Correct me if my understanding of your goal is wrong.

Comment: it doesn't have to be remote, in fact the website won't be hosted, it would just be run locally. So I'm basically looking for a GUI for a CSV python script.

Comment: @Kxa if your goal is to use HTML to implement a form of GUI, then this is your option. But if you are open to other GUI frameworks, take a look at [Tkinter](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TkInter). There are other options as well, but Tkinter is the classic one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML/CSS with python by building a webapp with a python backend. There are lots of framework avaiable that allow you to do that, such as [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/), [Pyramid](https://trypyramid.com/) and Flask.
I personally like to use [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) for small projects, since it's faster to prototype than django and also easy to learn/work with.